# w3c- error character "v "not allowed in prolog

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Hey I have an error in w3c.

```
Line 1, Column 1: character "v" not allowed in prolog
```

and

```
Line 1, Column 60: end of document in prolog
```

I am new to HTML and I am stuck can anyone help
Thanks

Comment: If you can provide some code and data you'll get quicker answers. Make sure that you have read how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake in validating your locally written code.

You can't paste a localhost URL in W3C as it doesn't know where that code is.

You have to use the https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and paste the source code there manually.